# Does Shifter gain the ability score bonuses from Major Aspect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wild-shape

When a shifter uses Major Aspect, it is treated as a Beast Shape II effect. The beast shape spells give you an ability score and natural armor bonus based on the size of your new form. Does a Shifter gain these increases when assuming Major Form, or only the benefits detailed in the Major Aspect entry?

Also, this doesn't work the same for the Elementalist Shifter?

Answer (score 1):

The rules for Wild Shape, in part, say -

> Each major form details the abilities the shifter gains with that major form and at what level; she gains these instead of the form abilities from beast shape II, **but she still gains beast shape II abilities that are size dependent.**

The abillity score modifiers granted by Beast Shape II are all linked to size changes, so should still be granted, in addition to anything the specific Aspect gives you.